# Run Python scripts on command line running Docker images

Tags: docker

I built a docker image using Dockerfile with Python and some libraries inside (no my project code inside). In my local work dir, there are some scripts to be run on the docker. So, here what I did

```
$ cd /path/to/my_workdir
$ docker run -it --name test -v `pwd`:`pwd` -w `pwd` my/code:test python src/main.py --config=test --results-dir=/home/me/Results
```

The command `python src/main.py --config=test --results-dir=/home/me/Results` is what I want to run inside the Docker container.

However, it returns,

```
/home/docker/miniconda3/bin/python: /home/docker/miniconda3/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
```

How can I fix it and run my code?

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-runtime-ubuntu18.04

MAINTAINER Me <me@me.com>

RUN apt update -yq && \
    apt install -yq curl wget unzip git vim cmake sudo

RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' docker && \
    adduser docker sudo && \
    echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

USER docker

WORKDIR /home/docker/

RUN chmod a+rwx /home/docker/ && \
    wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b && rm Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh 

ENV PATH /home/docker/miniconda3/bin:$PATH

Run pip install absl-py==0.5.0 atomicwrites==1.2.1 attrs==18.2.0 certifi==2018.8.24 chardet==3.0.4 cycler==0.10.0 docopt==0.6.2 enum34==1.1.6 future==0.16.0 idna==2.7 imageio==2.4.1 jsonpickle==1.2 kiwisolver==1.0.1 matplotlib==3.0.0 mock==2.0.0 more-itertools==4.3.0 mpyq==0.2.5 munch==2.3.2 numpy==1.15.2 pathlib2==2.3.2 pbr==4.3.0 Pillow==5.3.0 pluggy==0.7.1 portpicker==1.2.0 probscale==0.2.3 protobuf==3.6.1 py==1.6.0 pygame==1.9.4 pyparsing==2.2.2 pysc2==3.0.0 pytest==3.8.2 python-dateutil==2.7.3 PyYAML==3.13 requests==2.19.1 s2clientprotocol==4.10.1.75800.0 sacred==0.8.1 scipy==1.1.0 six==1.11.0 sk-video==1.1.10 snakeviz==1.0.0 tensorboard-logger==0.1.0 torch==0.4.1 torchvision==0.2.1 tornado==5.1.1 urllib3==1.23

USER docker
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: It seems like you'd get an equivalent and simpler setup by creating an ordinary Python virtual environment and running the `pip install` line to set it up; you can put that list of packages into a `requirements.txt` file to make it repeatable.  What are you gaining by using Docker here?

Comment: Yes, your comment is right. When running the command "docker run -it --name test -v `pwd`:`pwd` -w `pwd` my/code:test python src/main.py --config=test --results-dir=/home/me/Results", I got `/home/docker/miniconda3/bin/python: /home/docker/miniconda3/bin/python: cannot execute binary file`

Answer (score 1):

Try making the file executable before running it.

as John mentioned to do in the dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest

COPY src/main.py /usr/local/share/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/share/src/main.py      #<-**--- just add this also

# I have some doubts about the pathing 

CMD ["/usr/local/share/src/main.py", "--config=test --results-dir=/home/me/Results"]
```

Comment: Thanks, there are many python files, and sometimes I need to change my python files, so I think cp all my files to images is not practical. Instead, I want to run the task in command line. How can I fix my current issue?

Comment: docker run -it --name test -v `pwd`:`pwd` -w `pwd` my/code:test python chmod +x "src/main.py && src/main.py --config=test --results-dir=/home/me/Results"

Try running two commands sequentially like this.

Comment: Thanks, it is a bit weird, by replace the python commands with pwd, it also returns `/bin/pwd: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: Use your suggestion. I got `/bin/bash: python: No such file or directory`

Comment: I followed the code, https://github.com/oxwhirl/pymarl/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile and https://github.com/oxwhirl/pymarl/blob/master/run.sh

Answer (score 0):

You can run a python script in docker by adding this to your docker file:

```
FROM python:latest

COPY src/main.py /usr/local/share/

CMD ["src/main.py", "--config=test --results-dir=/home/me/Results"]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good method. But how can I fix my current issue? There are many command-line arguments to be passed to python, I prefer to run the code in the command line,